# Возможно ли скачать определенную версию проекта с github?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-clone

Есть публичный проект на GitHub. Мне необходимо скачать версию проекта, публикация которой была месяц назад. Возможно ли получить исходный код старой версии проекта?

Comment: commit версии ac5de1421f45aff3566e850e0b4ab18ce01f629f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Клонируете репозиторий как обычно, `git clone` *`<URI репозитория>`*
2. В истории (на сайте, или используя `git log`) находите нужный вам коммит или тег (по сути, точку во времени) и переходите на него: `git checkout` *`<хэш коммита или тег>`*. В вашем случае, `git checkout ac5de142` (можно указывать не полный хэш, а только уникальную его часть).
3. *(Опционально)* Делаете ветку `git checkout -b my-fork` и дальше работаете.

Answer (score 2):

Если известный хеш, то просто нужно сделать `git checkout тут_хеш` в папке проекта. Если проекта в папке нет, то нужно предварительно его с помощью `git clone` слить.